# reading Files in a loop [julia]?

Tags: file, file-io, julia

l have stored 10 files : file1, file2 until file10.
l coded a for loop in order to read the files by declaring a variable dc dc[1] until dc[10] corresponding to each file file1file10  but l got the error : not defined variable dc.

how to initialize dc  to be 500 by 500 elements

dc[1]  # (500,500) elements
.......dc[10] # (500,500) elements

```
for i in 1:10
        dc[i]=jldopen("/path to file/file$i.jld", "r")  do file
             read(file, "a")  # alternatively, say "@write file mini_batch"
             end
     end
```

Comment: Michael's answer is correct but please look carefully at the documentation carefully/do a google search before posting on SO! Have a read of these if you need some more help. http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/arrays/ & http://quant-econ.net/jl/julia_arrays.html

Comment: @AlexanderMorley is correct.  Also, beware that if you have too many negative vote questions, you can be subject to a question ban.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) for more details.  Everybody is learning, so don't take it too hard, but the more background reading that you can do on Julia basics (like in the links Alexander gave), and the more you can read SO information on posting good questions, the better of shape you'll be in.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to initialize the object `dc`, e.g.

```
dc = Array{Any}(10)
```

Note that this is not very good for performance - Julia works much better if you can specify the types for functions, arrays, etc.  But, since it isn't clear from the example what the elements would be, type `Any` will at least create something general that will work in your situation.  And, if performance isn't a specific concern, then it will do fine for the time being.

It looks like your objects will probably be 500x500 Array type objects.  If that is indeed the case, then you could preallocate an Array comrpised of 10 2-dimensional Arrays containing Float64 type objects (provided that is the data type you have).  E.g.:

```
dc = Array{Array{Float64, 2}}(10)
```

If you specifically want to preallocate with 500x500 Arrays, the matter is slightly more complicated.

Note that the syntax for initializing an Array is:

> **Array{T}(dims)**
>
> constructs an uninitialized dense array with element type T. dims may be a tuple or a series of integer arguments. The syntax Array(T, dims) is also available, but deprecated.

The type of an Array in Julia encompasses the number of the dimensions but not the size of those dimensions.  Thus, if you wanted to initialize `dc` specifically as an Array of 500x500 arrays, you would be best off with a comprehension:

```
dc = [Array{Float64}(500,500) for i in 1:10];
```

**Note**: replaced (soon to be deprecated) syntax, based on helpful comment from @David Sanders